# MySQL One row select only column without NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, row

```
    SELECT r.id AS Id, r.slot AS Slot, rg.name AS Grade, rt.name AS Type,
    r.main_stat AS Main Stat, r.stat01 AS 1st Substat, r.stat02 AS 2nd Substat,
    r.stat03 AS 3rd Substat, r.stat04 AS 4th Substat,
    CASE WHEN r.isEquipted = 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS isEquipted      
    FROM runes r                                                                           
    INNER JOIN rune_grade rg                                                                  
    ON r.grade_id = rg.id                                                                  
    INNER JOIN rune_type rt                                                                   
    ON r.type_id = rt.id                                                                    
    WHERE r.id = 7;
```

I have this query, that gives me only one record. This '7' in WHERE clause is variable in my code.
I want to remove columns that gives me NULL values.
This query returns:

`ID    Slot    Grade    Type    M Stat   1st Stat    2nd Stat     3rd Stat     4th Stat`

`7       4     normal   swift  spd-24      NULL        NULL         NULL         NULL`

if Where clause is equal to other id, 1st 2nd 3rd 4th Stat can have values.

`ID    Slot    Grade    Type    M Stat   1st Stat    2nd Stat     3rd Stat     4th Stat`

`6       3     normal   swift  spd-24     atk-32      hp-355         NULL         NULL`

Sorry for bad english.. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` to filter out rows where all `[X Stat]` columns are `NULL`:

```
WHERE r.id = 7 
  AND COALESCE(r.stat01, r.stat02, r.stat03, r.stat04) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @KJELYAZKOV I edited with the actual column names as they are in the table and not the aliases.

Comment: yeah, I know but...     (`select r.id as Id, r.slot as Slot, rg.name as Grade, rt.name as Type, r.main_stat as Main Stat, r.stat01 as 1st Substat, r.stat02 as 2nd Substat, r.stat03 as 3rd Substat, r.stat04 as 4th Substat, case when r.isEquipted = 0 then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end as `isEquipted`
from runes r
inner join rune_grade rg 
on r.grade_id = rg.id
inner join rune_type rt 
on r.type_id = rt.id
WHERE r.id = 7 
  AND COALESCE(r.stat01, r.stat02, r.stat03, r.stat04) IS NOT null;)

Comment: For r.id=7 you will not get any results because all the columns are NULL. Did you try it for r.id=6?

Comment: Do I need to remove these columns from SELECT above ?

Comment: What do you mean? You want in the results only the non null columns? If this is the case then you can't with SQL. A query returns always the same number of columns.

Comment: Well, then it won't happen. Sorry Im new, I didnt knew that. Thanks, though.